# How to check empty TextField in XCTest and XCUITest

Tags: ios, ui-automation, xctest, xcuitest

I have to check if there is any `UITextField` is empty or contains any value using `XCUITest` or `XCTest`.  I was checking on many places and found `textField.Value` can be used to find out the result. But for me the problem is `textField.value` returns placeholder as value and hence it fails to detect empty field as empty.

Comment: i have added an answer for this. Please try and let me know your feedback

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this recently and as pointed out by @adamjansch for `UITextField` the `XCUIElement` will return the `placeholder` value if it is set and there is no text in the text field.

Given that, I ended up doing something like this:

```
let query = app.scrollViews.otherElements
let textField = query.textFields["textFieldIdentifier"]

if textField.value != nil,
   let aValue = textField.value as? String,
   let placeholderValue = textField.placeholderValue,
   aValue != placeholderValue

{
   // Do something with the text field; it has a value
   // so perhaps it needs to be cleared before a new
   // value is input.
   textField.buttons["Clear text"].tap()
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two cases to figure out wheter the textfield is empty. First one - Use standart bool value of `yourTextField.text == nil` and second check for the instance to have string of `""` -> This should for instance occur when user would write some text and then delete it...

So in code:

```
// The second condition will occur only if the text is not nil, so 
// it is okay to unwrap it like it.
 XCTAssertTrue(textField.text == nil || textField.text!.isEmpty)
```

Comment: This answer cannot work (for iOS at least). A text field in an iOS UI test is not accessed through a UITextField object, so the properties `text` and `text.isEmpty` will not be available. Instead access to a text field is through an XCUIElement object, and the only way to get the text is through the `value` property. However, that value is populated if either the main text *or* the placeholder text is set, hence the OP's problem.

Comment: Do you try it before write this, you cannot use `textField.text` in iOS UI Test as adamjansch said.

Comment: Can someone else please write me that it won't work please?

Comment: @DominikBucher Let me know how my answer doesn't work for you and I'll be happy to update it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, however I demand more answers

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround for your problem. If you dont want to get the placeholder

- First click on the textfield

  ```
  textField.tap()
  ```
- Get the value from the textfield element

  ```
  let pageTitle = textField.value as? String
  var titleLength = pageTitle?.characters.count
  XCTAssertTrue(titleLength==0, "Title is empty")
  ```

Comment: You miss checking for nil in the titleLenght property.

Comment: @DominikBucher i am checking the string count. if count is 0 then it is definitely empty or nill. Why downvote it dear.

Comment: Okay dear. Since your answer is almost complete wrong, I will tell you the wrong aspects:

1. For swift 4 - `characters` property of String is deprecated

2. You are comparing nillable, so the assert will fail when the titleLenght is nil (Which is right assumption here)

3. Because of this, you are not covering all the cases.

4. TextField.value is complete nonsense because it returns instance of UITextField again, not the actual string, therefore there are just functions `value(for key:)` which are not safe to call.

Comment: Since OP gets the placeholder value from so to avoid it i just suggest to tap on that field first so that he can avoid getting the placeholder text. OP can decide what idea suits for him best. And there is no tag that it should be on swift 4 or not. OP can change into desired api on what he is working.

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution which should work (apart from in one situation*). XCUIElement has a property `placeholderValue`, which should contain the text field's placeholder text. So try this:

```
let textfield = XCUIApplication().textFields["textFieldIdentifier"]

if let textFieldText = textField.value as? String,
   textFieldText.isEmpty == false,
   textFieldText != textField.placeholderValue {
    // Do the thing that requires the text field *not* to be empty
}
```

* The one scenario where this won't work is if the text entered in the text field *is the same* as the placeholder's text. Then we're in Failsville.

However, as this is a UITest, I would think you should have some control over what gets entered into this text field.